# Do the conditional probabilities of equivalent measures merge in total variation?

Tags: probability-theory, measure-theory, proof-verification, conditional-expectation, probability-limit-theorems

Let $(\Omega, \mathcal{F})$ be a measurable space equipped with a *strictly increasing* filtration $(\mathcal{F}_{n})_{n \in \mathbb{N}}$. Let $P$ and $Q$ be probability measures on $(\Omega, \mathcal{F})$.

Suppose $P$ and $Q$ are equivalent in the sense that $P(A) = 0$ iff $Q(A) = 0$ for all $A \in \mathcal{F}$. Does the following result hold?

> $\sup_{A \in \mathcal{F}}|P(A \mid \mathcal{F}_{n}) - Q(A \mid \mathcal{F}_{n})| \to 0$ as $n \to \infty$ almost surely with respect to $P$ and $Q$.

**ADDENDUM**: Suppose that $\mathcal{F}_n \nearrow \mathcal{F}$. By the Levy 0-1 Law, both $P(A \mid \mathcal{F}_n)$ and $Q(A \mid \mathcal{F}_n)$ tend to $\mathbf{1}_A$ almost surely. So for this case, all that needs to be shown is that $P(A \mid \mathcal{F}_n)$ and $Q(A \mid \mathcal{F}_n)$ tend to $\mathbf{1}_A$ *uniformly* in $A$.

**ADDENDUM 2**: Here is an attempt at a solution for the case $\mathcal{F}_n \nearrow \mathcal{F}$. I would appreciate feedback.

We show that $|P(A \mid \mathcal{F}_n) - Q(A \mid \mathcal{F}_n)|$ is bounded by a quantity that is independent of $A$ and that tends to $0$ as $n \to \infty$. Let $q = dQ/dP$, and abuse notation by writing $A = \mathbf{1}_A$.

It's easy to show using the basic properties of conditional expectations that $$E_Q(A \mid \mathcal{F}_n) = E_P(Aq \mid \mathcal{F}_n)(E_P(q \mid \mathcal{F}_n))^{-1}.$$

Hence, omitting the subscript from $E_P$ henceforth, we have
$$P(A \mid \mathcal{F}_n) - Q(A \mid \mathcal{F}_n) = \frac{E(A \mid \mathcal{F}_n)E(q \mid \mathcal{F}_n) -  E(Aq \mid \mathcal{F}_n)}{E(q \mid \mathcal{F}_n)}.$$

By the equivalence of $P$ and $Q$, $q >0$ a.s., and $E(q \mid \mathcal{F}_n) \to q$ a.s. by the Levy 0-1 Law. It suffices to show that the numerator on the RHS tends to $0$ uniformly in $A$.

Using the basic properties of conditional expectations again, we find after some manipulation that

$$|E(Aq \mid \mathcal{F}_n) - E(A \mid \mathcal{F}_n)E(q \mid \mathcal{F}_n)| = |E[A(q - E(q \mid \mathcal{F}_n)) \mid \mathcal{F}_n]| \\ \leq E[|A(q - E(q \mid \mathcal{F}_n))| \mid \mathcal{F}_n] \leq E[|q - E(q \mid \mathcal{F}_n)| \mid \mathcal{F}_n].$$

Now, $E[|q - E(q \mid \mathcal{F}_n)| \mid \mathcal{F}_n]$ is independent of $A$. Moreover, $|q - E(q \mid \mathcal{F}_n)| \to 0$ as $n \to \infty $ because $E(q \mid \mathcal{F}_n) \to q$. Finally, 
$$|q - E(q \mid \mathcal{F}_n)| \leq |q| + \sup_n(|E(q \mid \mathcal{F}_n)|) = : Z$$

and $EZ < \infty$ because $\{ E(q \mid \mathcal{F}_n) \}$ is uniformly integrable and hence bounded in $L^1$. The dominated convergence theorem for conditional expectation now yields

$$E[|q - E(q \mid \mathcal{F}_n)| \mid \mathcal{F}_n] \to 0,$$ and we are done.

Comment: If $P(A|F_n)= E^P[I_A|F_n]$, clearly not. For example take $F_n={ \Omega, \emptyset}$ for all n. Then the fact that the measures are equivalent does not imply they are the same.

Comment: @Kolmo You're right. Michael Greinecker pointed something similar out to me a few days ago and I had meant to edit the post. I'm interested in the case where the $\mathcal{F}_{n}$ are _strictly_ increasing. I'll edit now.

Comment: You need $F_n\uparrow F$ to get any kind of convergence, never mind in total variation. Strictly increasing is not enough to guarantee this.

Comment: Also, in the addendum, you claim that $EZ < \infty$, which is not true in general.

Comment: As there are uncountable many sets $A$, I think you need the essential supremum, not the supremum.

Comment: @GeorgeLowther Thank you for your comments. Could you please tell me why my reasoning that $EZ < \infty$ is incorrect?

Comment: @GeorgeLowther Martingale convergence still applies to the case $\mathcal{F}_n \nearrow F_{\infty}  \subset \mathcal{F}$, so it's not true that the filtration must increase to $\mathcal{F}$ to get any kind of convergence. Also, I'm not sure where you think an essential supremum is needed and what difference it would make.

Comment: Uniformly itegrable does not imply that the supremum is bounded in $L^1$. Coincidentally, I recently posted some counter examples on my blog. These are continuous time martingales, but it is simple enough to discretise these. https://almostsure.wordpress.com/2016/09/12/martingales-with-non-integrable-maximum/

Comment: Your inequality following "after some manipulation" only holds almost surely. Both sides are only defined up to a zero probability set. Then, you cannot conclude that it holds simultaneously for uncountably many $A$.

Comment: If $F_\infty\not=F$ then your sequence converges to $\lvert P(A\mid F_\infty)-Q(A\mid F_\infty)\rvert$, which need not be zero.

Comment: I see. Thanks for clarifying that. I'd appreciate any further suggestions for how to fix this.

Comment: Well, the best you are going to get is uniform convergence to $P(A\mid F_\infty)-Q(A\mid F_\infty)$. I think that may be true, as long as you use the essential supremum. The supremum is not even well-defined (up to sets of zero probability). The argument needs to be improved. As stated, the addendum 2 does hold, just the intermediate statement that $EZ < \infty$ is false. The conclusion still holds though, which I can see by making use of Doobs $L^0$ maximal inequality, but it is a bit more difficult to prove than the argument used.

Answer (score 1):

If $\mathcal{F}=\lim_n\mathcal{F}_n$, we in fact have the following limit,
$$
{\rm ess\,sup}_Z\lvert E_P[Z\mid\mathcal{F}_n]-E_Q[Z\mid\mathcal{F}_n]\rvert\to 0,
$$
(almost surely), with the essential supremum taken over random variables $\lvert Z\rvert\le 1$ (you can restrict to $Z=1_A$ for sets $A\in\mathcal{F}$ if you prefer). Setting $q=dQ/dP$ and $q_n=E_P[q\mid\mathcal{F}_n]$ then $E_Q[Z\mid\mathcal{F}_n]=E[Zq\mid\mathcal{F}_n]/q_n$.
\begin{align}
\lvert E_P[Z\mid\mathcal{F}_n]-E_Q[Z\mid\mathcal{F}_n]\rvert
&=\lvert E_P[Z(q_n-q)\mid\mathcal{F}_n]\rvert/q_n\\
&\le E_P[\lvert q_n-q\rvert\mid\mathcal{F}_n]/q_n
\end{align}
(almost surely). As the right hand side does not depend on $Z$, the inequality holds for the essential supremum. By martingale convergence, $q_n\to q > 0$ almost surely. So, it just remains to show that $E_P[\lvert q_n-q\rvert\mid\mathcal{F}_n]$ goes to zero almost surely. 'Dominated convergence' as stated in the question gives, for any $\epsilon > 0$,
\begin{align}
&E_P[1_{\{q_n-q > \epsilon\}}\mid\mathcal{F}_n]\to0\\
&E_Q[1_{\{q_n-q > \epsilon\}}\mid\mathcal{F}_n]\to0
\end{align}
almost surely. So,
$$
E_P[1_{\{q_n-q > \epsilon\}}(q_n-q)\mid\mathcal{F}_n]=q_nE_P[1_{\{q_n-q > \epsilon\}}\mid\mathcal{F}_n]-q_nE_Q[1_{\{q_n-q > \epsilon\}}\mid\mathcal{F}_n]
$$
tends to zero almost surely and,
\begin{align}
E_P[\lvert q_n-q\rvert\mid\mathcal{F}_n]&=E_P[2(q_n-q)_++q-q_n\mid\mathcal{F}_n]\\
&=2E_P[(q_n-q)_+\mid\mathcal{F}_n]+E_P[q-q_n\mid\mathcal{F}_n]\\
&=2E_P[(q_n-q)_+\mid\mathcal{F}_n]\\
&\le2E_P[1_{\{q_n-q > \epsilon\}}(q_n-q)\mid\mathcal{F}_n]+2\epsilon\\
&\to2\epsilon
\end{align}
almost surely. As $\epsilon > 0$ can be taken arbitrarily small, the limit
$$
E_P[\lvert q_n-q\rvert\mid\mathcal{F}_n]\to0
$$
(almost surely) follows.

Comment: What is $
q_nZ_n-Z_n-q_nZ_\infty+Z_\infty
$?

Comment: Also, I'm still not completely clear on your point about swapping the supremum for the essential supremum? Do you claim that the result is false for the supremum? Or is your point that the argument that I began, and that you corrected and completed, simply doesn't work for the supremum?

Comment: That was a copy & paste error. Removed it

Comment: The terms that you are taking the supremum over are only defined up to a zero probability set. As the uncountable union of zero probability sets can be the whole space, the supremum can be anything just by using different realizations of the conditional expectations.

Comment: Are you familiar with Blackwell & Dubins (1962) on merging of opinions? That paper uses the supremum for what is, as far as I can tell, essentially the same result.

Comment: No, but it is freely available (https://projecteuclid.org/download/pdf_1/euclid.aoms/1177704456). Where is the statement you refer to.

Comment: First paragraph and Main Theorem on p. 883.

Comment: Maybe I'm missing something, but I don't see where it is taking an uncountable supremum of conditional expectations.

Comment: The distance metric at the top of p.883 is defined by taking a supremum over all events in $\mathcal{F}$. The Main Theorem on the same page claims that the conditional probabilities merge with respect to this metric. See also the calculation at the top of p.885.

Comment: But it is the supremum of $\lvert\mu_1(D)-\mu_2(D)\rvert$, which is real valued (not a random variable) and is not a conditional expectation.

Comment: They do assume that the conditional probabilities are regular ("predictive" as they say) in that $P(\cdot \mid \mathcal{F}_n)(\omega)$ is a probability measure on $\mathcal{F}$ for each $\omega \in \Omega$.

Comment: ok, I think I see what you are getting at. It looks at the difference between $P^n(x_1,\ldots,x_n)$ and $Q^n(x_1,\ldots,x_n)$. But, these are regular conditional probabilities, so it is a bit different from just looking at conditional expectations.

Comment: So, in your proof above, if we assume the conditional probabilities are regular, is that sufficient to conclude that the result holds for the supremum?

Comment: It is if we also assume that $E_Q[Z\mid\mathcal{F}_n]=E_P[Zq\mid\mathcal{F}_n]/q_n$ everywhere, otherwise I am not so sure.

Comment: And in the statement, they say "there exists a conditional distribution $Q^n$ such that...". So, that leaves you free to choose $Q^n$ such that the identity $E_Q[Z\mid\mathcal{F}_n]=E_P[Zq\mid\mathcal{F}_n]/q_n$ holds everywhere.

Comment: also, looking through that paper, the result can be proven in a more straightforward way just from martingale convergence, without using optional sampling or Doob's maximal inequality.

Comment: I simplified the proof, and it is now closer to the one given in the paper you mentioned.

Comment: Yes it does, but I don't use that identity. I made a further edit to clarify.

Comment: I also learned something, by looking at the paper you referred to. Initially I was thinking Doobs maximal inequality was required, but the trick of applying bounded convergence for conditional expectations with respect to both $P$ and $Q$ really simplifies things.